# center of the window in bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a single page site where I need to put a picture at the center of the window and some text on it.

In bootsrap3, the grid system allocates screen space from to to bottom(row wise).

I want the picture to be placed exactly at the center of the screen(not at the center of any row). Can somebody help me ?

Here is my code

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="center-block">
                    <div class="body-data" data-link="about-me">
                      <div class="col-lg-8">
                          <img src="images/profile.jpg" alt="image with rounded corners" class="img-rounded"/>
                          <br/><br/>
                          <p>I am a masters student in TU Darmstadt. I am from Bhubaneswar(a tiny city in the eastern part of India). Now I am in Darmstadt in Germany.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body-data" data-link="education">
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <p class="text-center">b masters student in TU Darmstadt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body-data" data-link="work">
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Company Name</th>
                              <th>Location</th>
                              <th>Position</th>
                              <th>Technology</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Tata Consultancy Services</td>
                              <td>Mumbai</td>
                              <td>Systems Engineer</td>
                              <td>C,C++, Oracle, Shell Script</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Siemens Technology Services</td>
                              <td>Bangalore</td>
                              <td>Systems Engineer</td>
                              <td>C++, Qt, Shell Script</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body-data" data-link="contact">
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                          <dt>Email Id</dt>
                          <dd>dhal[dot]asik[at]gmail[dot]com</dd>
                          <dt>Twitter</dt>
                          <dd><a href="https://twitter.com/asit_dhal">@asit_dhal</a></dd>
                          <dt>Github</dt>
                          <dd><a href="https://github.com/asit-dhal">asit-dhal</a></dd>
                        </dl>  
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
// content here
</div>
```

Or you can also try

**Html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row vcr">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">stuff</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.vcr{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r59mqgub/)

Comment: he has <div class="col-lg-8"> so it would need to be <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

Comment: It places the data at the middle of the row. I need things at the middle of the screen. Like the paragraph should be at the middle of row and middle of column(middle of screen).

Answer (score 0):

In the Bootstrap documentation under "Offsetting columns" http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid you can see a reference to this.  Or change  to  the column offset will work the best for what you want though.